# uploadify : restrict image dimension

Tags: uploadify

I am using Uploadify to upload image in php(codeigniter). Tested with the sample php file that come with the uploadify package. It works. However, I can't get onUploadError triggered. The sample php code has:

```
if (in_array($file_ext,$fileTypes)) {
    $newFileName = mt_rand() . time() . '.' . $file_ext;
    $targetFile = rtrim($targetPath,'/') . '/' . $newFileName;
    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
    echo $newFileName;
} else {
    echo 'Invalid file type.';
}
```

js is very simple as following:

```
$('#file_upload').uploadify({
        'fileTypeDesc' : 'Image Files',
        'fileTypeExts' : '*.gif; *.jpg; *.jpeg; *.png',
        'swf'      : '/static/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
        'uploader'      : '/static/uploadify/uploadify.php',
        'onUploadError' : function(file, errorCode, errorMsg, errorString) {
            console.log('The file ' + file.name + ' errorCode ' + errorCode + ' errorMsg ' + errorMsg + ' errorString ' + errorString);
        },
        'onUploadSuccess' : function(file, data, response) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

when the `Invalid file type.` is echoed to the frontend. the `onUploadSuccess` is triggered instead of `onUploadError`. It seems odd to me that there is no indicator to stell uploadify there is an error from php.

the only way that triggers `onUploadError` is to set a non 200 http header before echoing. however, `onUploadError` function arguments `errorCode`, `errorMsg`, `errorString` are the http code and the echo content(error message) is lost.

**UPDATES**

I modified the question title so it speaks the real problem I was trying to solve. And I have since found the solution.

Comment: Came here looking for an image dimension solution, only to find that that wasn't the real topic of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got sometime to tackle this problem and here are my steps to solve it.

first, the problem of `onUploadError` is not fired is because the file has been uploaded successfully

second, uploadify queue limit and upload limit are updated accordingly upon successful upload regardless of detection of wrong image dimension from the backend.

So the solution is that my backend checks image dimension and responds with a json data with error message which shown to user. also reset uploadify, really it is swfupload, variable `successful_uploads`. that makes sure the queuelimit or upload limit not messed up. sample code:

```
'onUploadSuccess' : function(file, data, response) {
    var obj = eval('(' + data + ')');
    if ( obj.success ) { alert('uploaded') }
    else { 
        var stats = this.getStats();
        this.setStats({successful_uploads: stats.successful_uploads - 1});
    }
 }
```

see swfupload setStats method http://demo.swfupload.org/Documentation/#setStats